# How to use lists of coordinates to get colors from an image using colors.rgb2lab and imread

Tags: python, list, numpy, imread

I don't know much about python. Trying to learn it. But I need to get the code running from a project built by someone else.

```
figure()
im = imread('Input.jpg')
x = []
y = []

def ext(a,b,i):
    a,b=np.round(a),np.round(b)
    x.extend(arange(a,b,1).tolist())
    y.extend((ones(int(b-a))*i).tolist())

val = color.rgb2lab((im[x,y]/255.).reshape(len(x),1,3)).reshape(len(x),3)
```

I am getting the following error on the last line above.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\John\Downloads\test.py", line 58, in <module>

val = color.rgb2lab((im[x,y]/255.).reshape(len(x),1,3)).reshape(len(x),3)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I have tryed many things from using map(int,x) to try to convert the lists x and y to arrays, resulting in more different errors. I can't list all the different things I have tried. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:
Solved. I wanted to show the full code file, so I tried to find a python file host. Luckily I found www.pythonanywhere.com. I executed the test.py file on www.pythonanywhere.com and it mentioned that some code is deprecated, but still it executed the file properly and I got the result I wanted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are indexing your containers with empty lists. You are also never running `ext` function (if that is the purpose).

Comment: @armatita I have edited the question with solution. Thanks for your help.